# Do I need a wizard to rename namespaces and project names in a Visual Studio multi-project template?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, templates, vsix, project-template, visual-studio-templates

I'm using VS 2010, and I need to do some multiproject template samples, using VSIX, not necessarily a Wizard, but it works fine for what we need.

My project names should be:

*CompanyName.SolutionName.Accounting

CompanyName.SolutionName.Banking*

And they are

*CompanyName.App.Accounting

CompanyName.App.Banking*

Do I need to change in .vstemplate and put

```
<Name>CompanyName.$safeprojectname$</Name>
```

or do I need to change something on .csproj? Or both? Or something else?

I don't want to use a wizard to do it, I just want to use VSIX commonly.

Tks in advance, guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to modify .cproj file of your project.

Replace

```
<RootNamespace>$safeprojectname$</RootNamespace>
```

with

```
<RootNamespace>CompanyName.$safeprojectname$.Banking</RootNamespace>
```